# Can the Sword of Gryffindor absorb power from spells?

Tags: harry-potter

The Sword of Gryffindor takes on that which makes it stronger. If the sword were to deflect like the killing curse, hit with the spell [Sectumsempra], or another magical spell, could the sword absorb the power of those spells to make it stronger?

Comment: I think this is an excellent question -- I hope it receives more answers and more detailed answers than it has so far. I am pondering the answer myself! :)

Answer (score 4):

The only evidence that we have of the sword taking in anything is the case where it imbibed basilisk venom in chamber of secrets:

> “The sword can destroy Horcruxes! Goblin-made blades imbibe only that which strengthen them — Harry, that sword’s impregnated with basilisk venom!” - Hermione Granger

Deathly Hallows, chapter 15 (The Goblin’s Revenge)

Looking at the definition of "imbibe", it means "to drink". As a result, there is a strong indication that this is a *physical* process. The physical sword made contact with the physical venom.

There isn't any indication that the sword is a type of magical well as seen in the traditional sci-fi sense. In fact, there isn't any mention in the hp universe of a device that stores magic in an attempt to use it later. There is no need for one, since people are born with the ability to do magic and don't seem to run out, so why accumulate it?

Additionally, the performance of a spell requres skill, and is taught. The magic alone is not capable of being useful unless there was a mechanism by which it could be used usefully.

So it seems like the sword is limited to physical contact with physical objects. Even if it could store magic, why would anyone need to when they have magic themselves? And even if it did store magic, how would it use it?

It seems like this type of sword wouldn't really fit well into the hp canon since it utilises magic in a different way, that is by storing it instead of having magic as an inherent property.

Comment: "there isn't any mention in the hp universe of a device that stores magic in an attempt to use it later"...Well, in Deathly Hallows, we learn that Harry's wand "imbibed some of the power and qualities of Voldemort’s wand [...] and it regurgitated some of his own magic against him, magic much more powerful than anything Lucius’s wand had ever performed. ” Now, this might be related to the unique case of Harry , but it looks like wands can imbibe magical qualities. Of course, we don't know if this  also applies to the Sword of Gryffindor.

Answer (score -3):

First off, I love the movies and have only read the first few books. That out of the way, I feel that the sword would take in the spells "energy".

My thoughts are that say a killing spell is blocked by the sword takes the spells energy in. (Swords are used as weapons) So, when the user of the sword has intention to kill, one wouldn't need a "killing blow" to kill their opponent.

Kinda like dipping an arrow head into poison, maybe the cut wouldn't be fatal, but the poison will work it's way... The stronger the spell would be like a more potent poison,

Using a sword takes time and practice as well, just like learning the different spells, and say the user breaks their wand but the sword presented itself.